# карточки добавляются в конец списка, а после перезагрузки появляются в начале списка

Tags: javascript, promise

При добавлении карточки она добавляется только после перезагрузки страницы, хотя аналогичным способом делаю изменение данных пользователя на странице, они меняются сразу, без перезагрузки.

**Вот как реализовано изменение данных пользователя (они меняются без перезагрузки)**

```
_checkResponse(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    };
    return Promise.reject(`Ошибка: ${response.status}`);
  };

changeUserData(userName, userAbout) {
    return fetch (this._baseUrl + '/users/me', {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: this._headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: userName,
        about: userAbout
      }),
    })
    .then(this._checkResponse);
  };

export default class UserInfo {
  constructor (nameSelector, aboutSelector, avatarSelector) {
    this._nameSelector = document.querySelector(nameSelector);
    this._aboutSelector = document.querySelector(aboutSelector);
    this._avatarSelector = document.querySelector(avatarSelector)
  };

  getUserInfo() {
    return {
      name: this._nameSelector.textContent,
      about: this._aboutSelector.textContent,
      avatar: this._avatarSelector.src
    };
  };

  setUserInfo(userData) {
   this._nameSelector.textContent = userData.name;
   this._aboutSelector.textContent = userData.about;
   this._avatarSelector.src = userData.avatar;
  };
};

/* Создание данных профиля */
const userInfo = new UserInfo (
  '.profile__title', 
  '.profile__subtitle', 
  '.profile__avatar'
);

/* ФОРМА ПРОФИЛЯ */  

/* Хендлер отправки формы */
const handleFormEditSubmit = (newInputValues) => {
  api.changeUserData(newInputValues['input-name'], newInputValues['input-about'])
    .then((userData) => {
    userInfo.setUserInfo(userData)
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

**Но кода по такой же логике добавляю новую карточку на страницу, то она появляется уже только после перезагрузки страницы**

```
export default class Card {
  constructor ({cardData, handleLikeCard, handleCardClick, handleDeleteCard}, userId, templateSelector) {
    this._name = cardData.name;
    this._link = cardData.link;
    this._likes = cardData.likes;
    this._cardId = cardData._id;
    this._ownerId = cardData.owner._id;
    this._handleLikeCard = handleLikeCard;
    this._userId = userId
    this._templateSelector = templateSelector;
    this._handleCardClick = handleCardClick;
    this._handleDeleteCard = handleDeleteCard;
  };
/* Клонирование разметки карточки */
  _getElement() {
    const cardElement = document
      .querySelector(this._templateSelector).content
      .querySelector('.cards__card').cloneNode(true);
    return cardElement
  }
/* Наполнение разметки карточки */
  generate() {
    this._element = this._getElement();
    this._element.querySelector('.cards__title').textContent = this._name;
    this._cardImage = this._element.querySelector('.cards__pic');
    this._cardImage.src = this._link;
    this._cardImage.alt = this._name;
    this._deleteButton = this._element.querySelector('.cards__delete');
    this._likeButton = this._element.querySelector('.cards__like-button');
    this.updateDeleteButtonView();
    this.updateLikesView();
    this._setEventListeners();
    return this._element;
  };
/* Получение ID карточки */
  id() {
    return this._cardId;
  };
/* Проверка на наличие лайка пользователя */
  isLiked() {
    return Boolean (this._likes.find(userData => userData._id === this._userId))
  };
/* Изменение состояния лайка, в зависимости от наличия лайка пользователя */
  updateLikesView() {
    if (this.isLiked()) {
      this._likeButton.classList.add('cards__like-button_active');
    } else {
      this._likeButton.classList.remove('cards__like-button_active');
    };
    this._updateLikes();
  };

/* Актуализация количества лайков */
  _updateLikes() {
    this._element.querySelector('.cards__like-counter').textContent = this._likes.length;
  };

/* Проверка принадлежности карточки к пользователю */
  isCardOfUser() {
    return Boolean (this._cardId.find(cardData => cardData.owner_id === this._userId))
  };

/* Изменение состояния кнопки удаления карточки */
  updateDeleteButtonView() {
    if (this.isCardOfUser) {
      this._deleteButton.classList.add('cards__delete_inactive');
    } else {
      this._deleteButton.classList.remove('cards__delete_inactive');
    };
  };

/* Удаление карточки из разметки и из оперативной памяти */
  remove() {
    this._element.remove();
    this._element = null;
  };
/* Установка слушателей */
  _setEventListeners() {
    this._cardImage.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this._handleCardClick(this._link, this._name)
    });
    this._deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this._handleDeleteCard(this)
    });
    this._likeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this._handleLikeCard(this)
    });
  }
}

addNewCard(cardName, cardLink) {
    return fetch (this._baseUrl + '/cards', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: this._headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: cardName,
        link: cardLink
      }),
    })
    .then(this._checkResponse);
  };

/* ФОРМА ДОБАВЛЕНИЯ КАРТОЧКИ */ 

/* Хендлер отправки формы */
const handleFormAddSubmit = (newInputValues) => {
  api.addNewCard(newInputValues['input-place'], newInputValues['input-link'])
    .then((cardData) => {
      cardSection.addItem(createCard(cardData))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: они добавляются, решил пролистать вниз, они в конец попадают почему-то, а после перезагрузки уже в начало идут

Comment: Думал сделать через метод *reverse()*, но не могу понять куда его вставить правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил иначе, создал отдельный метод для отрисовки изначальных карточек и отдельный метод для добавления новых

```
export default class Section {
  constructor ({ renderer }, containerSelector) {
    this._renderer = renderer;
    this._container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
  };

  addInitialCards(element) {
    this._container.append(element);
  }

  addItem(element) {
    this._container.prepend(element);
  };

  renderItems (items) {
    items.forEach(item => this._renderer(item))
  };
};

/* ФОРМА ДОБАВЛЕНИЯ КАРТОЧКИ */ 

/* Хендлер отправки формы */
const handleFormAddSubmit = (newInputValues) => {
  api.addNewCard(newInputValues['input-place'], newInputValues['input-link'])
    .then((cardData) => {
      cardSection.addItem(createCard(cardData))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

/* Рендеринг карточек */
const cardSection = new Section({
  renderer: (cardData) => {
    cardSection.addInitialCards(createCard(cardData));
  }
}, '.cards');

/* Вывод данных пользователя и карточек на тсраницу*/
const getInfo = Promise.all([api.getUserData(), api.getCards()])
  .then(([userData, cardData]) => {
    userInfo.setUserInfo(userData);
    userId = userData._id;
    cardSection.renderItems(cardData);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```